# What is the status of the Inkscape Gradient Mesh Tool? I cannot activate it in version .92

Tags: inkscape, gradient-mesh

I have been searching various forums to try to get some information about this tool.

I have seen websites about how to turn it on through the Preferences window in Inkscape. When I have attempted to do so, I cannot type in a new keyboard shortcut. That field is not active for me.

I have been using Inkscape on and off for a couple of years to do some simple things. But, lately I have been doing more complex projects. And, having this tool would be very nice.

I have seen something about a Diffusion Curve application as an alternative.

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the [Gradient Mesh Tool](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Mesh_Gradients) may depend on the version of [Cairo library](https://cairographics.org/) used to compile your executable.

Basing upon your comment, for a *32-bit version of Windows* the Gradient Mesh tool is not available, see also [here](http://goinkscape.com/how-to-unlock-the-gradient-mesh-tool-in-inkscape/).